# Install new site from existing config plus data migration

Tags: 8, installation-profiles

I need to install a new site on drupal 8 from existing config plus data like content, users.

I used [config installer](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer) to install a new site from existing config.

How to make it import content after complete configuration import.

New ideas and other solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I found [multipurpose corporate profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/multipurpose_corporate_profile) a distribution which does the job and accelerates the development process.

It deserves discovering its key features.